# Using aliases with sass-loader to avoid relative path mess

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, sass-loader, webpack-file-loader

I have a `.scss` file in which I'm using a backgorund image (`background-image: url('../../../image.png')`). The `file-loader` webpack plugin detects that image and copies it when I'm building my app, which is great.

The problem is that I have quite some images and quite some `.scss` files, and I have a huge mess going in my code with all the relative imports.

Is there a way I can tell either `file-loader` or `sass-loader` that if I do `background-image: url('@alias/image.png')` I'm referring to the folder where `image.png` is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webpack already supports this https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#alias

you just need to set-up the alias in `css-loader`’s options and reference the image as `url(~alias/image.png)`

Comment: Yes, thank you :) Actually I already found that library and patched the bug it had in Windows: https://github.com/RobinCK/css-aliases/pull/2

Comment: This is not a library, it’s webpack’s official `css-loader`. Give it a try, it might not have that bug